# Best word to describe non-profit organization that mediates between private person and company

Tags: single-word-requests

Like title describes I need a word that best describes non-profit organization that mediates between company (as donor) and private person (as donee or receiver of that donation).

What is the right word for that?

As I know *mediator*, *intermediary*, *agent* etc. are words for person not organization.

Only word that I can think of is *medium*. Is it correct to name it that way?

Comment: Why do you think you can't use "agent" or "intermediary" for an organization?

Comment: I don't know, thats why I asked :) But in this case where organization is non-profit agent doesn't sound well to me. Like Max said in answer below it suits more for company. It is agency in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "medium", as a noun referring to a person, means "someone who claims to be able to contact the dead, via some special psychic ability".  So, don't use that.

The words you listed (*mediator, intermediary, agent*) can all apply to organisations as well as individuals, "mediator" & "intermediary" more so than "agent" (the company would typically be called an *agency* instead).

Another word used to describe a company which mediates between two parties is a "factor", though this may be purely a British usage.

If you could provide a link to the website of an example of this type of company that will help.

EDIT:

I just remembered that "Mediator", as a description of a company, tends to be used (I think) more in situations where there is some **hostility** between the two other parties - such as a difficult divorce, for example.  This reinforces the choice of "Intermediary", i think, in a situation where there the two sides are trying to help one another, and need some help doing it.  You could also use **"Facilitator"**, which suggests that the "inbetween" company has specialist skills which are needed to complete the negotiation (which, again, may be the case for you).  To spell this out a bit more:

**"Intermediary"** - acts as a shared point of contact between two parties

**"Mediator"** - acts as a shared point of contact between two parties which have some hostility towards one another (and thus need to be kept apart to avoid arguments)

**"Facilitator"** - acts as a shared point of contact between two parties who want to achieve the same thing together, but need some expert help to do so.

Comment: There is no website of that company. I'am building system that involves these 3 sides, so I'm trying to find best words for naming it in system.

Comment: I would probably go with "Intermediary" as a guess, then, without knowing any more about the company or situation.

Comment: You could also consider **go between**, although this can have negative connotations of shady deals. Other words to look into include **broker** for the noun, and **escrow** or **disbursement** for the activity.